# Insert data from form into table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table 'Invoices' which contain the fields `UserID`, `PurchaseOrderID` and `InvoiceRef` neither of them being primary keys.

I want to create a form with a table where I paste in invoices info and then on clicking a button VBA runs and pastes the data into the `Invoices` table. Most I can do but the SQL part I can not understand is how to prevent duplicates, by duplicate I mean an invoice with a with `UserID`, `PurchaseOrderID` and `InvoiceRef` that already exists in the `Invoices` table so for example if the `Invoices` table already contains:

```
UserID  | PurchaseOrderID |  InvoiceRef  
10001   | PO123123        |  9991
```

It will insert:

```
UserID  | PurchaseOrderID |  InvoiceRef  
10001   | PO123123        |  9992
```

but not:

```
UserID  | PurchaseOrderID |  InvoiceRef  
10001   | PO123123        |  9991
```

Below is the SQL I am playing with but am stuck at the WHERE clause:

```
    INSERT INTO INVOICES
      (UID, POID, REFID)
    SELECT IMPORT.UID,
           IMPORT.POID,
           IMPORT.REFID
    FROM INVOICES
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(STUCK HERE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICES
  ADD CONSTRAINT <name u wish> UNIQUE(UserID, PurchaseOrderID,InvoiceRef);
```

So, what it does is that whenever u insert a record, if combination of the three columns exists ,it won't let u insert that record.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to avoid duplicate writes, create index:

```
create unique nonclustered index x on INVOICES (UID, POID, REFID) with (ignore_dup_key=on);
```

this will not allow inserting duplicates (option `ignore_dup_key=on` does this)